# SQL Server one-to-many relational IF query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an `employees` table that has many `employee_records`. The `employee_records` table has a column named `event_type` and it is an enum that can be either `hire-date`, `promotion`, `termination`, `title-change`, or `rehire`. I am attempting to calculate an employees total time employed and make some calculations based on how long they have been employed.

How can I add a column that gives me the total days that they have been employed?

Essentially, I need to see if they have a record with the `event_type = termination` and if they do, then I need to see if they have a rehire date, and if they do, then I need to use their `rehire` date as the first day of their employment and calculate their time of employment that way.

As for a result, I simply need a `days_employed` column that reflects the actual amount of days they have been employed.

Here is what I have so far.

```
SELECT
    employees.id,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    email,
    event_type,
    CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, employee_records.created_at, SYSDATETIME()) < 365 * 5
           THEN 1
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, employee_records.created_at, SYSDATETIME()) < 365 * 10 
           THEN 2
        ELSE 3
    END AS benfits_type,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, employee_records.created_at, SYSDATETIME()) AS days_employed,
    employee_records.created_at AS hire_date
FROM 
    employees
JOIN 
    employee_records ON employees.id = employee_records.employee_id
ORDER BY 
    employees.id ASC;
```

Comment: How does calculating the time between the *termination* and the *rehire* determine "how long they have been employed"?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: My apologies. I fixed the question to state that I need to see of they have been terminated, then I need to see if they have been rehired. If they have been rehired, then that is their start date and I can use that to get their total time of employment.

Comment: Write a query to get all the records for `event_type = termination`. Then use that as a subquery and see if any records have a `rehire` date that are also in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you could do this. I'll post the query first and then walk through my explanation. If I understood you correctly, you were not looking for total days the employee was hired, but rather the total days of the employee's most recent employment at the company (Max hire date to max termination date or today).

```
;WITH hired 
     AS (SELECT employee_records.employee_id     id, 
                Max(employee_records.created_at) created_at 
         FROM   employee_records 
         WHERE  event_type = 'hire-date' 
         GROUP  BY employee_records.employee_id), 
     latest 
     AS (SELECT employees.id 
                id, 
                Isnull(Cast(Max(employee_records.created_at) AS DATE), Getdate() 
                ) 
                   created_at 
         FROM   employees 
                LEFT JOIN employee_records 
                       ON employees.id = employee_records.employee_id 
                          AND employee_records.event_type = 'termination' 
         GROUP  BY employees.id) 

SELECT *, 
       Datediff(day, hired, latestday) DaysEmployeed 
FROM   (SELECT hired.id, 
               hired.created_at AS Hired, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN hired.created_at > latest.created_at THEN Cast( 
                 Getdate() AS DATE) 
                 ELSE latest.created_at 
               END              AS LatestDay 
        FROM   hired 
               INNER JOIN latest 
                       ON hired.id = latest.id) JoinedCTEs
```

First of all I know you mentioned event_type is an integer, but for easy explanation I used a varchar.

Two CTEs to start.

First there is "hired" which will get you the latest hire date. So if an employee has multiple hire dates, it grabs the latest date.

Second there is "latest" which is the latest date an employee has a termination date, but also uses today's date as a placeholder date if an employee has never been terminated.

The final query joins the two CTEs and does a datediff by day to determine how many days an employee has been at the company. If the termination date is earlier than the hire date (An employee who was hired, terminated, rehired and is still with the company), it will take today's date as the latest date to count.